# SQL - question on transposing columns to row pivoting on multiple columns

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose, normalize, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here's my table

Table A

```
ID1, COL1, COL2, CODE A1, CODE A2, CODE A3,CODE B1, CODE B2, CODE B3, ..... CODE Z1, CODE Z2, CODE Z3
```

Here's the output I want:

```
ID1, COL1, COL2, CODE A1, CODE A2, CODE A3
ID1, COL1, COL2, CODE B1, CODE B2, CODE B3
    .
    .
    .
ID1, COL1, COL2, CODE Z1, CODE Z2, CODE Z3
```

Basically I want every occurrence of the combination CODE A1, CODE A2, CODE A3 output as new row along with the first 3 columns that uniquely identifies the record.

Let's say there are 26 occurrences of the combination of three codes, which is 78 columns.

I want to see this record split into 26 records.

Any suggestions you have would be really helpful.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Many databases support the Standard SQL lateral joins, which is the best approach.  But a more general approach is simply `union all`:

```
select id1, col1, col2, code_a1 as code from t union all
select id1, col1, col2, code_a2 as code from t union all
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Union defenitely works, just that i need 26 unions in this case. I am also working with similar requirements where i will need 100+ unions to get the desired results. I was trying to find a way to do this without writing a large number of unions in the query

Comment: @DERookie . . . There might be other approaches, but you still have not tagged the question to identify the database you are using.

Comment: tagged snowflake sql